# How to implement Redis Cache with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, redis

```
const redis = require('redis'); 
const getAsync = promisify(client.get).bind(client);

router.get('/get_all', async (req, res) => {
     let language = req.query.language;
     let data = '';
     try { 
         data = await getAsync(language);
     }
     catch (err) {
         console.log(err);
     }

     if (data) {
        console.log('Data is received from Redis Cache!');
        res.send(data);
     }
     else {
        try {
            const result = await Users.find({
               language: language
            });
            client.setex(language, 86400, JSON.stringify(result));
            res.send(result);
        }
        catch (err) {
           console.log('ERROR');
           console.log('MONGO DB RETURNED THE FOLLOWING ERROR');
           console.log(err);
           res.end();
       }   
     }
}
```

This is how i have implemented redis cache with mongod db.
* Is this the right way to do the implementation?
If it is wrong, please tell me how to implement.

One problem which i am facing now is, if i add try and catch block to 
    const data = await getAsync(language);

I am getting error.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error >originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch >block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). >(rejection id: 2)

Editted the code with two try and catch blocks.
Is this good way to implement redis with mongo?

Comment: Can you put the try - catch block starting from `let language = req.query.language;` ? If your `await getAsync` fails you aren't catching that.

Comment: Do you mean, one try block with two await and common catch block?

Comment: Well you could add another one which encapsulates everything / or have 2 which covers the if and else, or just one which covers everything. I'm just saying that your await statement needs to be covered.

Comment: I understand the point. If redis fails in the try block, will mongo db send the result? I want to implement, if redis fails to get the data, or there is no data in redis, i would like to get the data from mongo db

Comment: After your edits, are you still getting the same error?

Comment: No. I was getting that error because, inside try block, i was assigning `const data = `. Now i assigned `let data = ` out of the try block. Is this right way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187185/discussion-between-agriz-and-mavi-domates).